# Validar Radio Button

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola mi pregunta es como puedo validar si algún botón de mi Button Group esta seleccionado o no, por ejemplo si no hay ninguno seleccionado me mande un mensaje de error intente con unos métodos pero no da ( es un formulario )

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String nuevonombre = nombre.getText();
        String nuevoapellido = apellido.getText();
        String identificacion = id.getText();
        String telefono = ntelefono.getText();
        String p1 = placa1.getText();
        String p2 = placa2.getText();
        String h=horas.getText();



    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    if (nuevonombre.equals("") || nuevoapellido.equals("")
            || identificacion.equals("") || telefono.equals("")
            || p1.equals("") || p2.equals("")|| h.equals("")) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ningun campo puede quedar vacio");
    } else { //Aqui es donde empieza mi lio
        if (guardar.gettipoc().equals("")==false) {
            if (guardar.gettvehiculo().equals("") == false) {
                guardar.setnombre(nuevonombre);
                guardar.setapellido(nuevoapellido);
                guardar.setid(identificacion);
                guardar.settelefono(telefono);
                guardar.setplaca(p1, p2);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos han sido guardados");
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es necesario seleccionar el tipo de vehiculo ");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es necesario seleccionar el tipo de cliente ");
        }
    }


}                                        

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.setTvehiculo("Carro");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.dispose();

}                                        

private void jRadioButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.tcliente("A");

}                                             

private void jRadioButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.tcliente("B");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.tcliente("C");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.setTvehiculo("Camioneta");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.setTvehiculo("Bus");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Guardardatos guardar = new Guardardatos();
    guardar.setTvehiculo("Moto");
}                                             

private void jRadioButton5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField apellido;
private javax.swing.JTextField horas;
private javax.swing.JTextField id;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton4;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton5;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton6;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton7;
private javax.swing.JTextField nombre;
private javax.swing.JTextField ntelefono;
private javax.swing.JTextField placa1;
private javax.swing.JTextField placa2;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup tipocliente;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup tipodevehiculo;
```

Comment: Hola Steven, te sugiero agregués el código que has intentado. Es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información 

para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta  Jorgesys

Answer (score 3):

La forma de hacer individualmente es esta, claro aplicando que tienes 2 JRadioButton en un solo grupo

```
if(JRadioButton1.isSelected()==false && JRadioButton2.isSelected()==false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No selecciono ninguna opción");
}
```

Comment: su variable se llama `jRadioButton1` no `JRadioButton1`